# Field goal then safety in overtime?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

I know this scenario is extremely unlikely and will probably never occur, bit I am still curious. Say, overtime starts and Team A receives the ball first. They end up kicking a field goal and the ball goes to Team B. Team B then throws an interception to Team A. For whatever reason, on the interception return, the returner gets tackled in the end zone for a safety. What would then happen after that? Would Team B get another possession?

Comment: Does Team A carry the ball out of the end zone, then return it? If a player from Team A catches an interception in the end zone, and is tackled without the ball being advanced outside of the end zone, my understanding that that is a touchback.

Answer (score 5):

Team A would win the game in this scenario by one point. The safety counts but the game is over because Team B had a full possession.

The NFL [rulebook](http://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/image/rulebook/pdfs/19_2012_Overtime_Procedures.pdf) states:

> If the second team loses possession by an interception or fumble, the down will be permitted to run to its
>   conclusion, but if the second team’s possession has legally ended with the fumble recovery or interception,
>   any subsequent action will not affect the outcome of the game. (If the change of possession occurs in the
>   second team’s end zone, the score counts.)

Comment: Yes this isn't hard and it is a possession.   The more abstract question is what if a team botches a kickoff that results in a safety without ever possessing the kickoff.   I am sure the game is over on this but the wording isn't clear.    (example return man tries to catch ball at 3 yard line, hits his helmet and ricochets out of bounds in the end zone - game over?)

Comment: The official terminology is "opportunity to possess" - so the game will end even if the kicking team recovers an onside kick without the losing team actually touching the ball. https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.nfl.com/news/story/09000d5d827ee2c0/article/nfl-overtime-rules%3fnetworkId=4595&site=.news&zone=story&zoneUrl=url%253Dstory&zoneKeys=s1%253Dstory&env&pageKeyValues&sr=amp